# Passing barcode scan from textbox into a multiline textbox

Tags: vb.net, textbox, barcode

ok stuck on this a while and need advice - i have the form taking in the barcode scan into a textfield and using that textfield to query the database and it returns the PRICE from the products table. but when i scan the next item i get the error described below. its like its looking for two barcodes at the same time...but i have the textfield that holds the barcode set to clear after it has added the PRICE to the items textbox

my code:

```
    Private Sub txtTest_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, _

ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox3.KeyDown

        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then



            Dim con As New OleDbConnection

            Dim databaseprovider As String

            Dim dblocation As String





            databaseprovider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"

            dblocation = "Data Source = C:\Users\fergus\desktop\Loft Hair Studio Till App\loft.accdb"

            con.ConnectionString = databaseprovider & dblocation



            Dim queryLoft As String = "SELECT Price from Services where Field1 =" & TextBox3.Text & ""



            Dim command As New OleDbCommand(queryLoft, con)



            con.Open()



            Dim myreader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()



            myreader.Read() 'Read the next line from the DataReader



            'ListBox1.Text = myreader("price").ToString

            TextBoxList.Text = myreader("price").ToString

            'TextBox1.Text = myreader("price").ToString



            TextBoxTest.Clear()


        End If

    End Sub
```

error:

oledbexception was unhandled

syntax error(missing operator) in query expression 'Field1 = 61542451 61524587'

its like its searching the database for 2 barcode numbers at the same time.

seems odd.

any help appreciated

Comment: You're not clearing the text from the textbox that you're agonizingly, dangerously in-lining in your query string instead of parameterizing.

Comment: hi helrich im new to this. can you explain that to me? do you mean i need to use the clear method for textbox3?

Comment: Which textbox contains the scanned barcode?  It looks like TextBox3 is the one you are concatenating to your query, so it would seem that one is the one to clear.  I would second @helrich remark about using parameters instead of concatenation like this.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your event handler was named txtTest_KeyDown but it is handling TextBox3. I'm guessing you'll want to clear TextBox3 out after handling the scan.

```
Private Sub TextBox3_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox3.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        e.Handled = True

        Using cn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\users\fergus\desktop\Loft Hair Studio Till App\loft.accdb")
            cn.Open()

            Using cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT Price FROM Services WHERE Field1=?", cn)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scan", TextBox3.Text)

                Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    If reader.Read Then
                        TextBoxList.Text = reader("price").ToString
                        TextBox3.Clear()
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

Also, it's good practice to employ Using statements for disposable resources such as connections, commands, and readers.